# Solaris 11.3 ucred_getprojid incorrect behavior?

Tags: solaris

I've written a pair of TCP client/server which each call [`getpeerucred`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54766/getpeerucred-3c.html) on the other and then call [`ucred_getprojid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54766/ucred-getprojid-3c.html) print out the project id their respective peer. I see the following results:

1. Within within any distinct zone (global or `zlogin` to any single zone) the client/server pair both report proper project id from their peer.

   > # /usr/bin/id -p
   >   uid=0(root) gid=0(root) projid=1(user.root)
   >   # ./bind 5000
   >   Binding to port: 5000
   >   project id: 10
   >   ---------------
   >   $ /usr/bin/id -p
   >   uid=100(rpaisley) gid=10(staff) projid=10(group.staff)
   >   $ ./connect 127.0.0.1 5000
   >   project id: 1
2. With Trusted Extensions enabled using two differently labeled zones (it doesn't seem to matter if there's any dominance relationship, the same behavior applies) across a Multi-Level port both report `0` which is neither correct, nor the `-1` claimed from the [`ucred_getprojid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54766/ucred-getprojid-3c.html) manual page for when the project ID is not available.

   > # /usr/bin/id -p
   >   uid=0(root) gid=0(root) projid=1(user.root)
   >   # ./bin/bind 2000
   >   Binding to port: 2000
   >   project id: 0
   >   ---------------
   >   $ /usr/bin/id -p
   >   uid=100(rpaisley) gid=10(staff) projid=10(group.staff)
   >   $ ./bin/connect 10.10.10.1 2000
   >   project id: 0

Source code for server (named `bind`) is below. Program requires `-ltsol -lsocket -lnsl`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ucred.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(2 != argc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", *argv);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int port;
  char unused;
  if(1 != sscanf(argv[1], "%d%c", &port, &unused)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse port: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(-1 == s) {
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  struct sockaddr_in local;
  memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
  local.sin_family = AF_INET;
  local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  local.sin_port = htons(port);
  printf("Binding to port: %d\n", port);
  if(-1 == bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local))) {
    perror("bind");
    close(s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if(-1 == listen(s, 1)) {
    perror("listen");
    close(s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int c;
  struct sockaddr_in client;
  unsigned int clientlen = sizeof(client);
  c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &clientlen);
  if(-1 == c) {
    perror("accept");
    close(s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  close(s);

  ucred_t *cred = NULL;
  if(-1 == getpeerucred(c, &cred)) {
    perror("getpeerucred");
    close(c);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("project id: %d\n", ucred_getprojid(cred));
  ucred_free(cred);
  close(c);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Source code for client (named `connect`) Program requires `-ltsol -lsocket -lnsl`

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ucred.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(3 != argc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <ip addr> <port>\n", *argv);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int port;
  char unused;
  if(1 != sscanf(argv[2], "%d%c", &port, &unused)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse port: %s\n", argv[2]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  struct sockaddr_in srvaddr;
  memset(&srvaddr, 0, sizeof(srvaddr));
  srvaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  srvaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  if(0 == inet_aton(argv[1], &srvaddr.sin_addr)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Address invalid: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(-1 == s) {
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if(-1 == connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&srvaddr, sizeof(srvaddr))) {
    perror("connect");
    close(s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  ucred_t *cred = NULL;
  if(-1 == getpeerucred(s, &cred)) {
    perror("getpeerucred");
    close(s);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("project id: %d\n", ucred_getprojid(cred));
  ucred_free(cred);
  close(s);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The man page you linked for `getpeercred()` states:  "It is possible that all fields of the `ucred_t` are not available to all peer endpoints and all callers."  Not sure why you'd think you'd get consistent peer credentials across a TCP connection where you can't really trust what the other side sends.

Comment: @andrew-henle - The man page for `ucred_getprojid` states: "The `ucred_getprojid()` function returns the project ID of the process or -1 if the project ID is not available." Thus I expect either a valid project id, or -1 if it's not available. What was returned was neither -1, nor the valid project ID.

Comment: @andrew-henle As for consistent peer credentials across TCP: My entire connection is within the larger Solaris Trusted Extensions operating system.